# Для чего нужен прокси-сервер?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Мне дали тестовое задание, в котором нужно создать RSS ридер. Приложение получает конфигурационный файл, в котором указаны настройки для прокси-сервера.

Зачем нужен прокси, если я и так без проблем подключаюсь к адресу и получаю там нужную инфу?

Comment: Твою программу будут запускать не только на твоём компьютере. Возможно там доступ в интернет будет только через прокси. А вообще ты этот вопрос должен задать тому кто дал задание.

Comment: Прокси бывают разных видов. Open, Reverse. В задании что сказано? Для какой цели прокси должен применяться?

Comment: @Маг-притворщик, если мой ответ ниже полезен, то поставьте галочку слева.

Answer (score 0):

Прокси-сервер подменяет IP-адрес и трафик проходит через дополнительный сервер, на котором могут быть кэшированные данные или организованы дополнительные механизмы защиты данных.

**Используется в нескольких сценариях:**

Для обеспечения конфиденциальности, т.е. скрыть реальное посещение.

Для повышения уровня безопасности при выходе в сеть, т.е. атака будет направлена на прокси-сервер.

Для получения доступа к контенту, который существует только в определенной локации.

Чтобы ускорить доступ к некоторым ресурсам в Интернете.

Чтобы получить доступ к заблокированным страницам.